# Libgdx Table Background

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Another silly question! I am working with tables in my game because it is just a text-based game and does not require rendering of movement. I was wondering if there was a way to take a texture and then put another texture on top of it in a table, almost like the one texture was the background and another was the overlayed normal texture or imageButton. I know you can set a NinePath as a background but that does not help me I don't think because the image I have will not be changing size?

Comment: Have you tried 'Stack' in 'scene2d' class ? Or tried using a table in table?

Comment: Is there a way to flip an ImageButton or a Stack? (Like mirrored over y-axis) **@Tokenyet**

Comment: There is a 'flip' method in 'Texture' or 'Sprite'  class.